# node-gyp rebuild error while installing oracledb module

Tags: sql, node.js, linux, oracle11g, redhat

**Hi,
I am running node 4.4.2 on Red hat linux server and get an error while runnin**g-

```
# npm install oracledb
```

I have also downloaded and installed the instantclient rpm packages and also set the instantclient files to the environement variable. But i still am unable to install oracledb module. I am trying to get this bug fixed since almost a week and need help!

## python -V  -- gives me Python 2.6.6

## g++ -v -- gives me - build=x86_64-redhat-linux

Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) 
The Error Log is as given below -

```
[root@VMINBDEPRDDB opt]# npm install oracledb -g
|
> oracledb@1.10.1 install /opt/node-v4.4.7-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/oracledb
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/opt/node-v4.4.7-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/oracledb/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/oracledb/src/njs/src/njsOracle.o
In file included from ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.h:56,
                 from ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp:53:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:43:3: error: #error This version of node/NAN/v8 requires a C++11 compiler
In file included from /root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/node.h:42,
                 from ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp:51:
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h:336: error: expected unqualified-id before âusingâ
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h: In constructor âv8::MaybeLocal<T>::MaybeLocal()â:
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h:353: error: ânullptrâ was not declared in this scope
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h: In member function âbool v8::MaybeLocal<T>::IsEmpty() constâ:
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h:360: error: ânullptrâ was not declared in this scope
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h: In member function âbool v8::MaybeLocal<T>::ToLocal(v8::Local<S>*) constâ:
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h:364: error: ânullptrâ was not declared in this scope
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h: In member function âbool v8::WeakCallbackInfo<T>::IsFirstPass() constâ:
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h:430: error: ânullptrâ was not declared in this scope
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h: At global scope:
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h:469: error: expected unqualified-id before âusingâ
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h: In constructor âv8::Global<T>::Global()â:
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h:790: error: ânullptrâ was not declared in this scope
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h: In constructor âv8::Global<T>::Global(v8::Global<T>&&)â:
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h:815: error: ânullptrâ was not declared in this scope
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h: In member function âv8::Global<T>& v8::Global<T>::operator=(v8::Global<S>&&)â:
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h:827: error: ânullptrâ was not declared in this scope
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h: At global scope:
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h:852: error: expected unqualified-id before âusingâ
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h:1089: error: ânullptrâ was not declared in this scope
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h:1095: error: ânullptrâ was not declared in this scope
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h: In member function âv8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> v8::Function::NewInstance(v8::Local<v8::Context>) constâ:
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h:3205: error: ânullptrâ was not declared in this scope
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h: In member function âv8::Local<T> v8::MaybeLocal<T>::ToLocalChecked()â:
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h:7164: error: ânullptrâ was not declared in this scope
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:190,
                 from ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.h:56,
                 from ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp:53:
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h: At global scope:
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:13: error: expected unqualified-id before âusingâ
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:16: error: expected unqualified-id before âusingâ
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:19: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:24: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:31: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:36: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:41: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:46: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:51: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:59: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:64: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:69: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:76: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:83: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:91: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:98: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:108: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:114: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:118: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:125: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:130: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:135: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:139: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:145: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:150: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:156: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:162: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:168: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:174: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:180: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:186: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:194: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:201: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:205: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:209: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:213: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:217: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:237: error: expected initializer before â<â token
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:195,
                 from ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.h:56,
                 from ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp:53:
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:14: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of âMaybeLocalâ with no type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:14: error: expected â;â before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:16: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of âMaybeâ with no type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:16: error: expected â;â before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:26: error: âreturn_tâ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:27: error: âreturn_tâ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:28: error: âreturn_tâ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:29: error: âreturn_tâ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:30: error: âreturn_tâ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:31: error: âreturn_tâ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:32: error: âreturn_tâ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:42: error: âreturn_tâ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:43: error: âreturn_tâ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:44: error: âreturn_tâ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:45: error: âreturn_tâ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:46: error: âreturn_tâ does not name a type
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:59,
                 from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:195,
                 from ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.h:56,
                 from ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp:53:
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:18: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::ToFactory<v8::Boolean>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:19: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::ToFactory<v8::Number>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:20: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::ToFactory<v8::String>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:21: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::ToFactory<v8::Object>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:22: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::ToFactory<v8::Integer>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:23: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::ToFactory<v8::Uint32>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:24: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::ToFactory<v8::Int32>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:34: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::ToFactory<bool>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:35: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::ToFactory<double>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:36: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::ToFactory<long int>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:37: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::ToFactory<unsigned int>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:38: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::ToFactory<int>â does not name a type
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:196,
                 from ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.h:56,
                 from ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp:53:
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h: In function âv8::Local<T> Nan::imp::To(v8::Local<v8::Integer>) [with T = v8::Integer]â:
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:21: error: no matching function for call to âTo(v8::Local<v8::Integer>&)â
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h: In function âv8::Local<T> Nan::imp::To(v8::Local<v8::Integer>) [with T = v8::Int32]â:
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:28: error: no matching function for call to âTo(v8::Local<v8::Integer>&)â
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h: In function âv8::Local<T> Nan::imp::To(v8::Local<v8::Integer>) [with T = v8::Uint32]â:
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:35: error: no matching function for call to âTo(v8::Local<v8::Integer>&)â
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h: At global scope:
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:43: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of âMaybeLocalâ with no type
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:43: error: expected â;â before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:75: error: âreturn_tâ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:141: error: âreturn_tâ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:147: error: âreturn_tâ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:148: error: âreturn_tâ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:160: error: âreturn_tâ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:161: error: âreturn_tâ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:162: error: âreturn_tâ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:163: error: âreturn_tâ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:165: error: âreturn_tâ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:166: error: âreturn_tâ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:182: error: âreturn_tâ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:183: error: âreturn_tâ does not name a type
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:189,
                 from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:196,
                 from ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.h:56,
                 from ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp:53:
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:61: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::Factory<v8::Date>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function âstatic v8::Local<v8::Function> Nan::imp::Factory<v8::Function>::New(void (*)(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), v8::Local<v8::Value>)â:
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:95: error: âNewInstanceâ was not declared in this scope
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function âstatic v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> Nan::imp::Factory<v8::FunctionTemplate>::New(void (*)(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Signature>)â:
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:123: error: âNewInstanceâ was not declared in this scope
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: At global scope:
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:202: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::Factory<v8::RegExp>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:221: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::Factory<v8::Script>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:227: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::Factory<v8::Script>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:259: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::Factory<v8::String>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:267: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::Factory<v8::String>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:273: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::Factory<v8::String>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:280: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::Factory<v8::String>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:286: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::Factory<v8::String>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:291: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::Factory<v8::String>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:352: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::Factory<v8::UnboundScript>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:359: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::Factory<v8::UnboundScript>â does not name a type
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:196,
                 from ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.h:56,
                 from ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp:53:
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:293: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::Factory<v8::String>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:299: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::Factory<v8::String>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:305: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::Factory<v8::String>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:311: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::Factory<v8::String>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:317: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::Factory<v8::String>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:323: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::Factory<v8::String>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:329: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::Factory<v8::String>â does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:335: error: âreturn_tâ in class âNan::imp::Factory<v8::RegExp>â does not name a type
In file included from ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.h:56,
                 from ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp:53:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function âv8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Error(const char*)â:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:655: error: âclass v8::Local<v8::Boolean>â has no member named âToLocalCheckedâ
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function âvoid Nan::ThrowError(const char*)â:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:655: error: âclass v8::Local<v8::Boolean>â has no member named âToLocalCheckedâ
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function âv8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::RangeError(const char*)â:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:656: error: âclass v8::Local<v8::Boolean>â has no member named âToLocalCheckedâ
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function âvoid Nan::ThrowRangeError(const char*)â:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:656: error: âclass v8::Local<v8::Boolean>â has no member named âToLocalCheckedâ
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function âv8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::ReferenceError(const char*)â:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:657: error: âclass v8::Local<v8::Boolean>â has no member named âToLocalCheckedâ
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function âvoid Nan::ThrowReferenceError(const char*)â:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:657: error: âclass v8::Local<v8::Boolean>â has no member named âToLocalCheckedâ
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function âv8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::SyntaxError(const char*)â:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:658: error: âclass v8::Local<v8::Boolean>â has no member named âToLocalCheckedâ
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function âvoid Nan::ThrowSyntaxError(const char*)â:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:658: error: âclass v8::Local<v8::Boolean>â has no member named âToLocalCheckedâ
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function âv8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::TypeError(const char*)â:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:659: error: âclass v8::Local<v8::Boolean>â has no member named âToLocalCheckedâ
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function âvoid Nan::ThrowTypeError(const char*)â:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:659: error: âclass v8::Local<v8::Boolean>â has no member named âToLocalCheckedâ
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: At global scope:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:667: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:689: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:705: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:718: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:735: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:741: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:749: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:756: error: expected initializer before â<â token
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:762: error: expected initializer before â<â token
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h: In member function âvoid Nan::Callback::SetFunction(const v8::Local<v8::Function>&)â:
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/v8.h:3021: error: argument dependent lookup finds âclass v8::Setâ
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1398: error:   in call to âSetâ
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In member function âvoid Nan::AsyncWorker::SaveToPersistent(const char*, const v8::Local<v8::Value>&)â:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1518: error: âclass v8::Local<v8::Boolean>â has no member named âToLocalCheckedâ
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In member function âv8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::AsyncWorker::GetFromPersistent(const char*) constâ:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1536: error: âclass v8::Local<v8::Boolean>â has no member named âToLocalCheckedâ
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In member function âvirtual void Nan::AsyncWorker::HandleErrorCallback()â:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1570: error: no matching function for call to âNew(const char*)â
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function âvoid Nan::imp::SetMethodAux(T, v8::Local<v8::String>, v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate>, ...)â:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1872: error: there are no arguments to âGetFunctionâ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of âGetFunctionâ must be available
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1872: note: (if you use â-fpermissiveâ, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function âvoid Nan::SetMethod(HandleType<T>, const char*, void (*)(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&))â:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1884: error: âclass v8::Local<v8::Boolean>â has no d Nan::SetAccessor(v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate>, v8::Local<v8::String>, void (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), void (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<void>&), v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::AccessControl, v8::PropertyAttribute, Nan::imp::Sig)â:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1924: error: âNewInstanceâ was not declared in this scope
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function âbool Nan::SetAccessor(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::String>, void (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), void (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<void>&), v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::AccessControl, v8::PropertyAttribute)â:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1967: error: âNewInstanceâ was not declared in this scope

../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function âvoid Nan::SetIndexedPropertyHandler(v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate>, void (*)(uint32_t, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), void (*)(uint32_t, v8::Local<v8::Value>, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), void (*)(uint32_t, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Integer>&), void (*)(uint32_t, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Boolean>&), void (*)(const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Array>&), v8::Local<v8::Value>)â:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:2096: error: âNewInstanceâ was not declared in this scope
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function âvoid Nan::SetCallHandler(v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate>, void (*)(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), v8::Local<v8::Value>)â:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:2151: error: âNewInstanceâ was not declared in this scope
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function âvoid Nan::SetCallAsFunctionHandler(v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate>, void (*)(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), v8::Local<v8::Value>)â:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:2173: error: âNewInstanceâ was not declared in this scope
In file included from ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.h:56,
                 from ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp:53:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function âvoid Nan::Export(Nan::ADDON_REGISTER_FUNCTION_ARGS_TYPE, const char*, void (*)(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&))â:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:2200: error: no matching function for call to âNew(const char*&)â


../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In member function âvoid Nan::Tap::pass(const char*)â:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:2227: error: âclass v8::Local<v8::Boolean>â has no member named âToLocalCheckedâ
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: At global scope:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:2251: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of âMaybeLocalâ with no type

../src/njs/src/njsConnection.h:423: error: expected â,â or â...â before â<â token
../src/njs/src/njsConnection.h:424: error: âHandleâ has not been declared
../src/njs/src/njsConnection.h:424: error: expected â,â or â...â before â<â token
../src/njs/src/njsConnection.h:424: error: âstatic void Connection::GetBinds(int)â cannot be overloaded
```

ed void
    ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp:146: error: âHandleâ was not declared in this scope
    ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp:146: error: expected primary-expression before â>â token
    ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp:146: error: âtargetâ was not declared in this scope
    ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp: In static member function âstatic Nan::NAN_GETTER_RETURN_TYPE Oracledb::GetConnectionClass(v8::Local, const Nan::PropertyCallbackInfo&)â:
    ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp:558: error: no matching function for call to âNew(std::string&)â
    ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp: In static member function âstatic Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE Oracledb::GetConnection(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo&)â:
    ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp:770: error: no matching function for call to Oracledb::Async_AfterCreatePool(uv_work_t*)â:
    ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp:1034: error: no matching function for call to âNew(std::string&)â
    ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp: At global scope:
    ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp:1074: error: variable or field âinitâ declared void
    ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp:1074: error: âHandleâ was not declared in this scope
    ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp:1074: error: expected primary-expression before â>â token
    ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp:1074: error: âtargetâ was not declared in this scope
    ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp:1083: error: âinitâ was not declared in this scope
    ../src/njs/src/njsOracle.cpp:1083: error: too many initializers for ânode::node_moduleâ
    make: *** [Release/obj.target/oracledb/src/njs/src/njsOracle.o] Error 1
    make: Leaving directory `/opt/node-v4.4.7-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/oracledb/build'
    gyp ERR! build error 
    gyp ERR! stack Error:`make` failed with exit code: 2
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/opt/node-v4.4.7-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
    gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64
    gyp ERR! command "/opt/node-v4.4.7-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/node-v4.4.7-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd /opt/node-v4.4.7-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/oracledb
    gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.7
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
    gyp ERR! not ok 
    npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64
    npm ERR! argv "/opt/node-v4.4.7-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/node-v4.4.7-linux-x64/bin/npm" "install" "oracledb" "-g"
    npm ERR! node v4.4.7
    npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

```
npm ERR! oracledb@1.10.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the oracledb@1.10.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the oracledb package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs oracledb
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls oracledb
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /opt/npm-debug.log
```

Any Help will be really appreciated...

Comment: You probably need a newer compiler. Try gcc/g++ 4.8.5 or newer, that's at least what is required to build node.js itself and so should be sufficient for compiling and linking node addons (like the oracle db addon here).

Comment: my current g++ version displays as gcc version- `4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) ` .  yum install unzip libaio gcc-c++ doesnot seem to work. Is there a way for me to uninstall the current gcc version and reinstall 4.8.5?, if there is please tell me how. Also, if I uninstall will the uninstall and reinstall of 4.8.5 have an imapact on the server ?

Comment: What OS are you using? CentOS/RHEL 5? 6?

Comment: I am using -- Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Release:        6.3

Comment: For CentOS/RHEL 6.x you can install devtoolset-4, which will get you an even newer compiler (gcc/g++ 5.2.x as of this writing). See: https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-4/

Comment: I had the same issue with CentOS. this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166124/how-to-install-node-oracledb-module-on-aws-centos6-through-command-line