# How to install node-oracledb module on AWS centos6 through command line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, centos6, node-oracledb

I am working on a project where I want my Node.js based backend to communicate with Oracle DB, Locally while development on windows system it wasn't difficult to install the pre requisite for node-oracledb module as mentioned here https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-931127 but now when I want to install the same pre requisite for centos6, I am facing issues.

List of pre requisite,

1. C Compiler with support for C++ 11.
2. Python.
3. Oracle Instant Client "basic" and "SDK" packages.

installing first two wasn't a challenge but finding rpm package for 3 is a tuff task.

Note: Everything has to be done using the Command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the search and effort I am finally able to install oracledb on my Centos system through the command line.

Please follow below steps on Command line as root user (Assuming Python is already installed):

1) Download required rpm Oracle instant client packages.

```
wget ftp://ftp.icm.edu.pl/vol/rzm6/linux-slc/centos/7.1.1503/cernonly/x86_64/Packages/oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm

wget ftp://ftp.icm.edu.pl/vol/rzm6/linux-slc/centos/7.0.1406/cernonly/x86_64/Packages/oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm

wget ftp://ftp.icm.edu.pl/vol/rzm6/linux-slc/centos/7.0.1406/cernonly/x86_64/Packages/oracle-instantclient12.1-sqlplus-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

Above commands will download rpm packages for oracle instant client.

2) Install Downloaded rpm packages.

```
[~]: sudo rpm -ivh oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:oracle-instantclient12.########################################### [100%]
[~]: sudo rpm -ivh oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:oracle-instantclient12.########################################### [100%]
[~]: sudo rpm -ivh oracle-instantclient12.1-sqlplus-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm 
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:oracle-instantclient12.########################################### [100%]
```

3) Download the repo files for DevTools2, a Red Hat package that contains a supported C++11 compiler.

```
wget http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-2/devtools-2.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/devtools-2.repo
```

4)  Install the compiler and support tools.

```
yum install devtoolset-2-gcc devtoolset-2-binutils devtoolset-2-gcc-c++
```

Above step will download Oracle instant client, C++ compiler and DevTools2 compiler. Now it's time to install oracledb.

Before you can compile C++11 code with the DevTools2 compiler, you need to enable it in a new shell:

```
scl enable devtoolset-2 bash
```

Now, install oracledb

```
npm install oracledb
```

This will install oracledb.

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle Instant Client libraries are currently not available via RPM. As a workaround, many folks download the libraries the normal way and then put them somewhere they can access them over the network. Then they use a command line tool like curl to pull them in when needed.

Comment: I think you meant NPM not RPM?

Comment: I meant RPM, as in the command line tool, not the file format. Same goes for Yum and NPM! :)

Comment: Instant Client RPMs have to be installed with either the rpm or yum command line tools.  (What am I missing in the general problem to be solved?)  Also the Instant Client RPM packages are on ULN for users with Oracle Linux support, so those users don't even need to downloaded them separately.

Comment: I think the issue is that he can't get the RPMs through the command line. I'm suggesting he get them once and put them somewhere he can get them via the command line.

Comment: Thanks, your comments helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

Instant Client RPMs are available for [32-bit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxsoft-082809.html) and [64-bit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html) Linux.  (The Instant Client home page is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index.html).)  Since Centos isn't an officially supported Linux, YMMV with the RPMs.

If the RPMs aren't usable for whatever reason, then download the Instant Client ZIP files, unzip them, and create the symbolic link `ln -s libclntsh.so.12.1 libclntsh.so`.

The Instant Client libraries will need to be in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or you can use ldconfig similar to:

```
sudo sh -c "echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf"
sudo ldconfig
```

You will also need the OS libaio package installed.  Using `yum` on the RPMs will pull this dependency in automatically, or you can install it separately.